# Twilio Conversation API: how to filter conversations/channels by member/participant identity

Tags: twilio-conversations

At server-side, We want to fetch all the Conversations/Channels by member(participant) identity.
Is there a way to do it using JAVA SDK for Twilio Conversations API?